# Getting elements children with certain tag jQuery

Tags: jquery, dom, tags, css-selectors, element

I'm trying to get all the input elements from a certain form from jQuery by providing only the name of the form and only knowing that those wanted fields are input elements.

Let's say:

```
<form action='#' id='formId'>
<input id='name' />
<input id='surname'/>
</form>
```

How do I access them individually with jQuery?
I tried something like `$('#formId > input')` with no success, in fact an error came back on the console `"XML filter is applied to non-XML value (function (a, b) {return new (c.fn.init)(a, b);})"`

Maybe I have to do it with .children or something like that? I'm pretty new at jQuery and I'm not really liking the Docs. It was much friendlier in Mootools, or maybe I just need to get used to it.

Oh and last but not least, I've seen it asked before but no final answer, can I create a new dom element with jQuery and work with it before inserting it (if I ever do) into de code? In mootools, we had something like `var myEl = new Element(element[, properties]);`
 and you could then refer to it in further expressions, but I fail to understand how to do that on jQuery

What I ended up doing was something like this: `$('#where').before("<a id='linkId' href='#'>Link Text</a>")` but this defeats the requirement of working with it before inserting it if you know what I mean.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope this answers your questions.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
        // Question part 1
    var formInputs = $("form#formId :input");
    formInputs.each(function(index) {
         alert(index + ': ' + $(this).attr("id") + "=" + $(this).val());
    });

        // Question part 2
    var a = $("<a id='linkId' href='#'>Link Text</a>");
    a.click(function(){alert("hello")});
    $('#where').before(a);


});
</script>

<form action="#" id="formId">
  <input id="name" type="text" value="foo" />
  <input id="surname" type="text" value="bar" />
  <div>
  <input id="phone" type="text" value="911"/>
  </div>
</form>
</div>
<div id="where"></div>
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want all descendants then @woland's answer works.  If you really only want the direct children as indicated by your > then

```
$('#form').children('input')
```

Wolands matches name, surname and phone.  Mine matches just name and surname

```
<form action='#' id='formId'>
<input id='name' />
<input id='surname'/>
<div>
<input id='phone'/>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: What's the difference then? `#formId > input` should do the job. +1 anyway, good answer.

Comment: In css selectors, the difference between "#formId > input" and "#formId input" is that the ">" only matches elements which are directly below the #formId in the dom.  "#formId input" matches any descendant.  The input could be nested in 15 divs and it would still match.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how it works:

```
$('#formId input')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to loop through all of the inputs, take a look at the [`each()` function](http://api.jquery.com/each/) in jQuery:

Comment: +1 for teaching me about the each function which even though I had read it, I also forgot about it.